# Express that a function is constant on a set

Tags: isabelle

I’m trying to express that a function `f` is constant on a set `S`, with value `r` My first idea was

```
f ` S = {r}
```

but that does not work, as `S` can be empty. So I am currently working with

```
f ` S ⊆ {r}
```

and it works okish, but I have the impression that this is still not ideal for the standard automation. In particular, `auto` would fail leaving this goal (irrelevant facts erased)

```
 2. ⋀xa. thunks (delete x Γ) ⊆ thunks Γ ⟹
         ae ` thunks Γ ⊆ {up⋅0} ⟹
         xa ∈ thunks (delete x Γ) ⟹
         ae xa = up⋅0
```

Sledgehammer of course has no problem (`metis image_eqI singletonD subsetCE`), but there are a few occurrences of this. (In general, `⊆` does not seem to work with `auto` as good as I’d expect).

There there a better way to express this, i.e. one that can be used by `auto` more easily when occurring as an assumption?

Comment: Using `!! x. x ∈ S ⟹ f x = r` seem to work okaish, and better than `∀ x ∈ S. f x = r`, at least in situations where `auto`’s limits are stressed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it, since I didn't have any examples handy. But you might try the following setup.

```
definition "const f S r ≡ ∀x ∈ S. f x = r"
```

Which is equivalent to your definition:

```
lemma
  "const f S r ⟷ f ` S ⊆ {r}"
  by (auto simp: const_def)
```

Then employ the following simp rule:

```
lemma [simp]:
  "const f S r ⟹ x ∈ S ⟹ f x = r"
  by (simp add: const_def)
```

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Oh sorry, you just wrote something similar in a comment (after I started typing my answer) ;)

Comment: It’s not similar; you introduce a new name and rely on the simplifier to make the connection. It might work well if both assumptions of the simp-lemma are readily available, but it still might be weaker than using the meta-implication directly, which can be used by `auto` to “try things out”.

Comment: You can also use the [simp] lemma as a destruction rule with auto. If all your use cases require the instance only for solving equalities in the conclusion, you could also use the similar rule `const f S r ==> x : S ==> r = r' ==> f x = r'` as an elimination rule. My feeling is that a separate constant with proper intro/elim/dest rules works better than the solution with `image`, because `image` requires several reasoning steps that you could combine in a single one for a constant of your own.

Comment: I tried the above, but that rule makes the simplifier loop. Maybe I have more luck with an elim rule.

Comment: The elim rule did not quite cut it for me, but I had more luck with `[dest]: "const_on f S x ⟹ y ∈ S ⟹ f y = x"`, at least in this instance. And in most but the most simple cases I have to use `fastforce` instead of `auto`. This is still mostly guesswork here...

Answer (score 1):

The Analysis library defines

```
definition constant_on  (infixl "(constant'_on)" 50)
  where "f constant_on A \<equiv> \<exists>y. \<forall>x\<in>A. f x = y"
```